# Starting MVC PHP - am I doing it right?

Tags: php

Im starting with MVC and I'd like you to see my code. Am I doing right? What can I improve in my classes?

### Controller

```
class Logar extends Controller {

    private $view;
    private $modelDAO;

    function __construct() {
        $this->modelDAO = new LogarModel();
        $this->view = new LogarView();
    }

    public function Login() {
        if ($this->modelDAO->Login($_POST['funcionario'], $_POST['senha'])) {
            $idFuncionario = $this->modelDAO->rows['idFuncionario'];
            parent::redirect("view/funcionario/index.php");
        } else {
            $this->view->show("Funcionario nao cadastrado");
        }
    }

}

class controller {

    function redirect($url){
        header("location: {$url}");
    }
}
```

### Model

```
class LogarModel extends Model {

    function __construct() {
        $this->conectar();      
    }

    function Login($funcionario, $senha) {
        $sql = "select * from funcionario where login = ? and senha = ? ";
        $this->read($sql);
        $this->bindar(1, $funcionario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $this->bindar(2, $senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $this->executar();
        $this->contar();
        $this->pegar_dados();
        $this->desconectar();
        if ($this->linhas == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class model {

    function conectar(){
        $this->conn = new Connection();
    }
    function read($readQuery){
       $this->stm =  $this->conn-> prepare($readQuery);
    }
    function bindar($n,$var,$extensao){
        $this->stm->bindparam($n,$var,$extensao);
    }
    function contar(){
        $this->linhas = $this->stm->rowcount();
    }
    function pegar_dados(){
        while($this->rows = $this->stm->fetch()){
            return $this->rows;
        }
    }
    function executar(){
        $this->stm->execute();
    }
    function desconectar(){
        $this->conn = null;
    }
}
```

### View

```
class LogarView extends view {

    function __construct(){
    }
    function mostrarlogado(){

    }
}

class view {

    function view(){

    }

    function get_var($var,$value){
        $this->var = $value;
    }

    function show($value){
        $this->value = $value;
        echo $this->value;
    }
    function alertar($value){
        echo "<script>alert('{$value}')</script>";
    }
}
```

So, how am I going?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you understood how MVC works, and you are doing it right. The helper functions such as `redirect()` are in the correct classes. A few comments on the code itself:

1. I'd recommend to add an `exit;` statement after sending headers in `redirect()`. It will be easier to understand the code, since you can now think of the `redirect()` as a `return`, which will help you avoid mistakes.
2. [Don't store your password in plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database).
3. Symply use `return $this->linhas == 1;` at the end of your login function.
4. Your `model` class simply translates the PDO interface into Portuguese, this is not an interesting layer of abstraction in my book. :)
5. Declare the variables you use, eg. `$this->stm` or `$this->conn`.
6. You are probably going to want an easier way to make requests when you will have dozens of them, but right now it's OK.

Comment: how a redirect will help me to avoid mistakes? i did not understand.

Comment: If there is no `exit()` in the redirect method, then the script will continue to execute. The server won't close the connection, and the client will wait for some other info. If you print anything afterwards, the client will probably never see it, since you issued a redirection. Stating that a redirect() contains an exit makes it clear that nothing can happen after a redirect. It works for your code since you don't do anything in Login() after calling redirect(), but if you were, it wouldn't work. I'd be glad to explain a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use for Redirection

// in controller class

```
public function redirect($url) {
// $url => array('controller' => 'goto_controller', 'action' => 'action_of_the_controller')
        if (is_array($url)) {
            debug($url);
        } else {

// login  or /home/login   or /admin/projects/add etc.
            debug($url);
        }
    }
```

if you want to redirect to the controller then use proper way for MVC. 
If you want with custom redirect then in same controller or in any other custom location you can goto with without array, you can set redirect from out of project using without array.
the Redirection method is upto you. 
You can redirect with
 - Location:
 - using javascript:
but if you are using `header("Location: url");` method you must have to add "exit()" after using the Location header.

Comment: You're doing the same thing no matter if $url is an array or not, why not simply do `debug($url);` ?